# Cloudinary with rails won't show my picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I am developing a Rails application and I want to upload a picture directly from my browser using [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/).

I followed all [steps from the Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration) page and ended up with a box and a question mark after I "uploaded" it, no picture at all. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you're trying

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you have used. But you should use carrierwave with cloudinary. Cloudinary having some complex way to handle display and save image if you don't use carrierwave.

But carreirwave provide simpler way to achieve uploading and display image.

[Without using carrierwave](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration)

[Using  carrierwave in compbination](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the sample project and then check the differences:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album